# Facebook mobile App responsive

Tags: facebook, mobile-website, facebook-apps, responsive-design

I have an existing facebook app (tab and canvas) and I want to make it accessible via mobile devices.

Do I have to create a "real" mobile web app eg with jquery mobile, or can I turn the app into an responsive app?

In fact, I've already tried using css3 media queries and it works fine on my mobile Safari, but not in the native Facebook App for iPhone.

So my question is: Is it possible to use media queries for my own app in the native Facebook mobile App?

Thanks

Comment: The facebook tabs that you have access to do not appear inside the iphone facebook app as options. YOu still get access to the Photos, Events etc but the other stuff is missing for me.

Comment: That's because there are no "Tab Apps" for mobile devices. If you provide a mobile link in the app's settings you can access your app via search. In the native Facebook App for iPhone (I don't know how this is working for the native Android FB App) your App only gets indexed for the search when you have 20 (I can't find the exact number right now but I think it's 20) monthly users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you can design/implement every fb-app in a responsive way. you don't need to have jquery mobile.

have you tried max-width or max-device-width within your media queries? please also have a look at our latest blog post to the topic: [how to link to your tab app for mobile usage](http://garage.socialisten.at/2013/01/how-to-link-to-your-facebook-tab-app/).

Comment: Hey Johannes,
I just tried it again and now it works. Unfortunately I don't know why it didn't work back then - and I can't reproduce the problem.
Well - at least everything's working now as expected and I will mark your answer as correct.
thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=579864128801274&version=v2.0";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://your-web-site.com" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Just focus on **data-width="100%"** It works fine for me.

Comment: I followed your suggestion to the letter and mine doesn't work. Thoughts?

Here's my link - [Website](http://jarednewnam.com/south/graduation/2015/index2.html)